# Error installing snowflake connector for python

Tags: python, snowflake-connector

When I try to download snowflake connector as following https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector.html I get an error for **`metadata-generation-failed`**.
Specifically I get an error saying `NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'pkg-config'`.

I've never seen this error, nor have I found anything online to help. I'm trying to install on Mac M1, which potentially could be the issue? Any thoughts as to what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is an issue with M1 chips on MAC.

More discussion [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/986).

Can you try installing python connector with this

```bash
pip install --no-binary snowflake-connector-python
```

There are other work-around mentioned in the above article, so please test those as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded pip and re-tried and it worked!! It is on M1 chip mac.

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

and then

pip3 install snowflake-connector-python